# WPF MVVM Dynamic control creation

Tags: dynamic, mvvm, telerik, controls

I am developing a MVVM/WPF application where in I have a usercontrol(WPF) which is designed as a  Applicatio form and it has got  Alias and Email-Id(Key/Value pair) field at the end, which will be input in textbox and these textboxes should be dynmically generated on click of button(+), my concern is placing the cotrol in View from view model- As I am using Grid rows/Column.

Alias1                Email1
Aliaas2               Email2

Any pointers or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add some relevant code to your question so we can better understand your scenario.

Comment: Hi, Assuming I have 
<telerik:RadMaskedTextInput Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="20" SectionsNavigationMode="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,3,0,0" Name="radMaskedtxtRuleName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214" Mask="a200" />
Assuming I have a grid with three controls one listed above in a row and my requirement is upon clicking on a  button(+) beside row I want to generate another row with the same set of controls from view model is it possible with out codebehind code though viewmodel.